# Placing text under image that is floating left

Tags: html, css

I have successfully placed an image on the left like so:

```
<div class="Carl1">
<a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1940412145" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank"><img class="image-left" src="http://caribeauchamp.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/first-time-final-cover.jpg" alt="My First Time in Hollywood" />
<span><strong>Amazon</strong></span>
</a>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.Carl1 {
text-align: left;
}
.image-left {
    float: left;
    margin: 15px 20px 10px 0px;
    border: solid 4px #fff;

}
```

However my text appears on the upper right of the image when I want it to appear under the image. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A JSFiddle link is appreciated for this type of question. It lets us see the problem, use the browser's debugging tools, fork it, and share the solution back to you.

Answer (score 9):

Float needs to be cleared. Also you used span element, what is inline element by the default, you will need to set span element as block element.

Here is a **JSfiddle** link.

**[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/rrq87c6a)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="Carl1">
<a href="http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1940412145" target="_blank">
    <img width="100" class="image-left" src="http://caribeauchamp.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/first-time-final-cover.jpg" alt="My First Time in Hollywood" />

<span class="title"><strong>Amazon</strong></span>
</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.Carl1 {
text-align: left;
}
.image-left {
    float: left;
    margin: 15px 20px 10px 0px;
    border: solid 4px #fff;
}

.title {
    clear: left;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The float needs to be cleared otherwise the text will attempt to Wrap around the image

```
.Carl1 span{display:block;clear:both;}
```

Comment: This will work in this case, but this CSS is very brittle and counter-intuitive as it is turning an inline element into a block and will not work if the author decides the span really out to be, say, a `<p>`. I would rather see a new class created, or an entire container floated (with a set width). The container should include both the text and image, neither of which would need float or clear any more.

Comment: Yes that true but its really outside the scope of this question

Answer (score 3):

Your question indicates you haven't quite figured out how floats work. The answers here will solve your problem today, but I suggest learning more about CSS positioning.

[Here is a really great and classic tutorial on the subject](http://www.brainjar.com/css/positioning/). It’s old, but it’s good stuff. You will have a lot easier time with CSS afterwards, I promise.

Also, I’d specifically suggest that you *don’t* float this image by itself; instead, float the the whole container (`.Carl1`) and give it a `width`.

Compared to the other answers on this page, this solution is closer to expressing your intention *in code*. I assume you consider the whole `Carl1` div to be essentially one object whose contents should appear together. Floating them as one is true to this intention :)

Comment: This is what worked for me, to simply remove the float attribute.